# Why is Element not Found, Except in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why can't this JavaScript find the input element with id="filesToUpload" in the HTML below it, except in jsfiddle? In jsfiddle, this code provides the functionality to select multiple image files, and lists the image files selected. It fails in IE, FF, and Chrome, unless run in jsfiddle.

```
function fileSelect(evt) {
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        var files = evt.target.files;
        var result = '';
        var file;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            result += '<li>' + files[i].name + ' ' + files[i].size + ' bytes</li>';
        }

        document.getElementById('filesInfo').innerHTML = '<ul>' + result + '</ul>';
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }
}

document.getElementById('filesToUpload').addEventListener('change', fileSelect, false);
```

The HTML:

```
<body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
        <div class="row">
            <label for="fileToUpload">Select Files to Upload</label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="file" id="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" />
            <br />
            <output id="filesInfo"></output>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

As commented below, the doc was not ready.  Per Martin Carney, this simple wrapper does the trick (if not explain why it works without jQuery in jsfiddle):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('filesToUpload').addEventListener('change', fileSelect, false);
});
```

Comment: Probably an other case of [`DOM ready`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: Add the javascript _after_ the element and it will most likely work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try waiting until the document is ready before running `document.getElementById('filesToUpload'). . .`.

Easy way to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('filesToUpload').addEventListener('change', fileSelect, false);
});
```

Comment: This solves it. You beat me to it. I wonder why this works without jQuery in jsfiddle?

Comment: @Guessed because jsFiddle is set to *"Execute code on window load"* by default. (Check in the options on the left)